# GLFW (LWJGL) Input - Holding CTRL down blocks the CharCallback

Tags: java, input, keyboard, lwjgl, glfw

I try to implement a simple CTRL + V for some textfields inside my game. So I set a flag for CTRL in the KeyCallback whenever ctrl is pressed or released (i tested this one). When I try to type "V" now the CharCallback isn't called. Is it supposed to not work this way? If it is how do i do it right?

That's how I poll it inside the KeyCallback:

```
if(key == GLFW_KEY_LEFT_CONTROL && action == GLFW_PRESS) {
    controlPressed = true;
}
if(key == GLFW_KEY_LEFT_CONTROL && action == GLFW_RELEASE) {
    controlPressed = false;
}
```

I use glfwSetKeyCallback(...) to set the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intended behavior. The [documentation for glfwSetCharCallback](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__input.html#ga556239421c6a5a243c66fca28da9f742) says (emphasis mine):

> The character callback behaves as system text input normally does and **will not be called if modifier keys are held down that would prevent normal text input on that platform**, for example a Super (Command) key on OS X or Alt key on Windows. There is a character with modifiers callback that receives these events.

However, it also states that you can use a [char mods callback](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__input.html#ga3f55ef5dc03a374e567f068b13c94afc), which will be called even when a modifier key is pressed.

> This function sets the character with modifiers callback of the specified window, which is called when a Unicode character is input regardless of what modifier keys are used.

For example:

```
GLFWCharModsCallback charModsCallback = new GLFWCharModsCallback() {
    @Override
    public void invoke(long window, int codepoint, int mods) {
        // do something with the character and modifier flags
    }
};
glfwSetCharModsCallback(window, charModsCallback);
```

Comment: Ah yes, now I remember you can never type while holding down modifier keys. Thanks :)